# How do I write from a file to another using import?

Tags: python, string, file, import

The objective is to run the module "printReport" which reads the file "arrivals_14_16.txt" and writes the first four lines from the file in the file "text.txt". But it only writes the first line.

In the function "headerArrivalsFile" from the module "readInput.py", if I leave "print line," in the end the function prints the first four lines, but if I leave "return line," in the end it only returns the first line.

But the function "operationReport" from the module "printReport.py" only works if i leave the function "headerArrivalsFile" with "return" in the end, if I leave "print" the module "printReport.py" stops working.

Module: readInput.py

```
def headerArrivalsFile(file_name):
    """
    """
    inFile = open(file_name, "r")
    for line in inFile:
        if "Arrivals:" in line:
            break
        return line, ## print line, ## (How do I put this work with -> return line,) 
    inFile.close()
```

Module: printReport.py

```
from readInput import headerArrivalsFile

def operationReport(inputFile, outputFile):
    """"
    """"
    inFile = open(inputFile, "r")
    outFile = open(outputFile, "w")
    for line in headerArrivalsFile(inputFile):
        outFile.write(line)
    outFile.close()
    inFile.close()
```

inFile: arrivals_14_16.txt

```
Airport: Neverland
Number of belts: 3
Day: 06:11:2014
Period: from 14:00 to 16:00
Arrivals:
KLM75, Amsterdam, 14:35, 60, 50
AF111, Paris, 14:20, 50, 64
LH333, Frankfurt, 14:10, 112, 203
KLM71, Madrid, 14:55, 120, 100
TAP103, Salvador, 15:20, 174, 210
LH123, Berlin, 15:10, 115, 210
```

outFile: test.txt (What I want to get)

```
Airport: Neverland
Number of belts: 3
Day: 06:11:2014
Period: from 14:00 to 16:00
```

outFile: test.txt (What I get)

```
Airport: Neverland
```

Comment: IN the function, replace 'return' with 'yield' to make it a generator.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in a mismatch between what headerArrivalsFile() does, and what the calling code expects it to do. This line:

```
for line in headersArrivalFile(inputFile):
```

Tells python that the function will return something it will iterate over (a string, sequence, mapping, or generator). Your function (exactly as shown here)

```
def headerArrivalsFile(file_name):
    """
    """
    inFile = open(file_name, "r")
    for line in inFile:
        if "Arrivals:" in line:
            break
            return line, ## print line, ## (How do I put this work with -> return line,) 
    inFile.close()
```

returns None, so I'm surprised you see any output. The 'break' before the return takes you straight to the close when you find the Arrivals line. If you don't find it, you fall out of the loop and close the file. Neither route returns any value.

So that needs to be addressed first. You don't need any loops, simply:

```
def headerArrivalsFile(file_name):
    with open(file_name,"r") as infile:
        # Read the entire file, stripping *only* newlines
        contents = [l.rstrip('\n') for l in infile]

    if "Arrivals:" in contents:
        return infile[:infile.index("Arrivals:")]

    return contents
```

Note the use of 'with' to automatically close the file after reading it.

Now to the calling function

```
def operationReport(inputFile, outputFile):
    """"
    """"
    inFile = open(inputFile, "r")
    outFile = open(outputFile, "w")
    for line in headerArrivalsFile(inputFile):
        outFile.write(line)
    outFile.close()
    inFile.close()
```

You open the file in headerArrivalsFile(), so there's no point in opening it again here. Also, use 'with' again to ensure the file is closed even in an exception.

```
def operationReport(inputFile, outputFile):
    with open(outputFile, "w") as outFile:
        for line in headerArrivalsFile(inputFile):
            outFile.write(line+'\n')
```

Also note I have added back the stripped newline character

Comment: I will try your code. Regarding the "return" is misaligned. Should be aligned with the "if" and not with "breake".

Comment: Ok, that explains your "returns one line" comment. So your function exits as soon as it reads the first line. The for loop in operationReport() then iterates over the characters in the line you return and writes them out one character at a time. Remember, a string is (in a strange way) very much like a list of characters.

Comment: Actually, just spotted that sneaky comma in "return line," which makes the returned value a tuple - so it just writes out the line in one hit.

Answer (score 0):

'return' stops the execution of a function. No matter where it is in the code, it stops at 'return' or when there is no more code to execute, whichever comes first.

Either put the results in a list and then return that list or use yield instead.